# Rendered PNG image sequence shows up as 0KB

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, error, empty, image-sequence

My rendered image sequence show up as 0KB, empty file, and I do not know why. I'm using EEVEE engine to render.

I attempted to create an animation by rendering it as a sequence of PNG images and also using FFmpeg with MPEG4 format. I set the output directory, enabled overwriting of files, but the rendered image sequence ended up being empty (0KB), and the video wouldn't play.

An error message indicated that the images were either corrupted or still being processed. I'm not sure what went wrong. I made sure to disable both 'compositing' and 'sequencer' for output post-processing, but the issue persists.

Please let me know if there is anything else I can try.

Comment: under output menu make sure "File extension" is checked